# Open a URL from a windows form with credentials

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to open an external website with username and password.  I have the correct credentials but when I try the following code I get "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" error.

```
        Dim username As String = "username"
        Dim password As New System.Security.SecureString

        'Set value for SecureString type variable   
        Dim plainPassword As String = "pass"
        For Each c As String In plainPassword.ToCharArray
            password.AppendChar(c)
        Next c

        Dim IEprocess As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process
        IEprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "http://www.website.com/"
        IEprocess.StartInfo.UserName = username
        IEprocess.StartInfo.Password = password
        IEprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        IEprocess.Start()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to login to website i think best to use POST Methode from HTTP, and you must define your login page parameters user and password (Php,ASP.Net,JAVA recomded can use action methode).

```
Dim PostData As String = "define your action login" 'example https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym,username and Password parameters
    Dim bytes() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData)
    Dim httpReg As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.website.com/")
    httpReg.Method = "POST"
    httpReg.KeepAlive = True
    httpReg.CookieContainer = mainCookie
    httpReg.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    httpReg.Referer = "http://www.website.com/index.html"
    httpReg.ContentLength = bytes.Length
    Dim DtStream As Stream = httpReg.GetRequestStream()
    DtStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    DtStream.Close()
    Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse
    httpResponse = httpReg.GetResponse()
    mainCookie.Add(httpResponse.Cookies)
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim strSource As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    If strSource.Contains("Selamat Datang") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Sukses Login")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Gagal Login")
    End If
```

Referance Articel : http://tech.reboot.pro/showthread.php?tid=61