# open url that requires windows authentication from code behind VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows, authentication

I have an **html** page on my website that requires windows authentication to open.
I want to redirect from an **aspx** page to this **html** page directly from code without prompting the user to enter username and password.

I have tried this [Open a URL from a windows form with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762172/open-a-url-from-a-windows-form-with-credentials)

but it didn't work i kept on getting LogIn Failed. I am working on a vb.net website in vs 2012.

Comment: Two questions: Are the creds that you pass it valid creds? (sorry had to ask) and Do you have to use IE process? Maybe an httpwebrequest might work if you just want the data.

Comment: yes they are valid. I need to open the url and show content it doesnt matter which browser but mainly i most probably i will be using google chrome